# Why am I getting this ImportError trying import users model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

Have two files in the same directory level, `application.py` and `models.py`, the first contains the blueprints registres, initial login and index route and the secondary database models.

Models:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from src.application import db
from flask_login import UserMixin

class Usuarios(db.Model,UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = db.Column(db.String(), index=True)
    usuario = db.Column(db.String(), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    senha = db.Column(db.String())
    stats = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    role = db.Column(db.String())
    foto = db.Column(db.String())
    artigos = db.relationship('Artigos',backref='usuario',uselist=False)

class Artigos(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'artigos'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    titulo = db.Column(db.String(), index=True)
    id_usuario = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('usuarios.id'))
    text = db.Column(db.Text())
    data = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    stats = db.Column(db.Boolean())
```

Application:

```
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, render_template, request, abort, Blueprint, session, jsonify
from flask_login import LoginManager, logout_user, current_user, login_user, login_required
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres://postgres:postgres@192.168.10.102:5432/ntest"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

#Flask_Login
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

#Flask_Alchmey e migrate
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from src.models import Usuarios

....
```

I have been facing this boring ImportError problem since I've decided to use ORM and migrate my database. Im not knowing to spplit this files or call theirs imports. Anyone can help or suggest something?

```
(test) C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python\test\src>python application.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from src.models import Usuarios
  File "CC:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python\test\src\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.application import db
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python\test\src\application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from src.models import Usuarios
ImportError: cannot import name Usuarios
```

Comment: Can you post the `traceback`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular import where `application.py` is importing from `models.py`, but `models.py` needs to import from `application.py`.

This is a common occurrence with `flask`. The typical solution is to use the [application factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) pattern.